# converting program to list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm pretty confused about how to convert this program to a list comprehension. Any tips?

Here's the original code I wrote (also, I'm new to python, so you can tell me if this sucks, I don't mind) The code is supposed to use the built in chr() function to return a string that when printed, is an ascii chart, four entries across.(only using ascii values from 32 to 126 inclusive)

```
def GiveAsciiChart5():
    count = 4

    for value in range(32, 127):
        count += 1
        print " |ASCII Value|: ", "|",(value),"|", " |Character|: ", "|",chr(value),"|",
        if count % 4 == 0:
            print "\n",

        #print " |ASCII Value|: ", "|",(value),"|", " |Character|: ", "|",chr(value),"|",
def Main():
    GiveAsciiChart5()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Here is my attempt at making a list comprehension...it obviously doesn't work. I'm pretty confused at where to put the count variable in? I'm trying to reduce it using list comprehensions and str.join()s.

```
def GiveAsciiChart6():
    count = 3
    a = [ (i, chr(i))  for i in range(32,127)]
    for count in a:
        if count % 4 == 0:
            print "\n"
            print " |ASCII Value|: ", "|",(i),"|", " |Character|: ", "|",chr(i),"|",



def Main():
    GiveAsciiChart6()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

I know it has a ways to go and is pretty awful at present. I'm just pretty stuck and confused at how to format it in this way...any tips are appreciated, not expecting complete solutions as I would like to learn and understand what is going on. 
Thanks!

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what's going wrong in the second version?

Comment: create a function `foo` such that `foo(i)` returns the string you need. But remember that commands such as `print` does not belong inside list comprehension. comprehensions are *expresions*. not programs.

Comment: @user1850672 The second version is supposed to do the same thing.I'm just trying to get used to using list comprehensions, but am having trouble with them once they get more complex than doing simple loops through lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an equivalent solution using a list comprehension and the [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) built-in function:

```
def GiveAsciiChart5():
    vals = [(value, chr(value)) for value in range(32, 127)]
    for i, (v, c) in enumerate(vals):
        print " |ASCII Value|: ", "|", v, "|", " |Character|: ", "|", c, "|",
        if not i % 4:
            print "\n",
```

Notice that the comprehension is only useful for generating the values, the printing part is done afterwards. By using `enumerate()` and making good use of tuple unpacking I'm skipping the need for a counter.

Comment: I like how you did this. So 'i' is basically acting as the count? Enumerate is also pretty cool. I hear it really simplifies things.

Comment: @user2376566 yes, exactly! enumerate assigns a counter to each of the values. And coupled with automatic unpacking of values, we have all the variables we need right in the loop declaration!

Comment: That's really useful! Thanks so much for the help. I've only been doing python for about 5 weeks or so, and am coming from Google's app inventor block language. Definitely a learning curve...but it's all starting to make more sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

So as to not give the answer entirely away, I annotated the code.

```
for count in a: #the type of count would be a tuple containing (i, chr(i))
    if count % 4 == 0:  #so then what should this statement be?
       print "\n"
       print " |ASCII Value|: ", "|",(i),"|", " |Character|: ", "|",chr(i),"|", 
       # ^ remember, we are iterating through a list of tuples, the element
       # our iteration is on is called count (what's 'i' doing here?)
```

Comment: I see what I did wrong. Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute the snippet below in the terminal:

```
>>> count = 3
>>> a = [ (i, chr(i))  for i in range(32,127)]
>>> for count in a:
...     print count
```

You get

```
(32, ' ')
(33, '!')
(34, '"')
...
```

Now if you try a line like `(33, '!') % 4`, you'll get a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'tuple' and 'int'`.

As I see it, your list comprehension seems to be okay. You're running into a problem because you're trying to find the modulus of a tuple.

Comment: That definitely makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [(i, chr(i)) for i in range(32, 127)]

for v, c in a:
    print ' |ASCII Value|: | {v} | |Character|: | {c} |'.format(v=str(v).rjust(3), c=c),
    if v % 4 == 0:
        print
```

Output using `if v % 4 == 3:`

```
|ASCII Value|: |  32 | |Character|: |   | |ASCII Value|: |  33 | |Character|: | ! | |ASCII Value|: |  34 | |Character|: | " | |ASCII Value|: |  35 | |Character|: | # |
|ASCII Value|: |  36 | |Character|: | $ | |ASCII Value|: |  37 | |Character|: | % | |ASCII Value|: |  38 | |Character|: | & | |ASCII Value|: |  39 | |Character|: | ' |
|ASCII Value|: |  40 | |Character|: | ( | |ASCII Value|: |  41 | |Character|: | ) | |ASCII Value|: |  42 | |Character|: | * | |ASCII Value|: |  43 | |Character|: | + |
|ASCII Value|: |  44 | |Character|: | , | |ASCII Value|: |  45 | |Character|: | - | |ASCII Value|: |  46 | |Character|: | . | |ASCII Value|: |  47 | |Character|: | / |
|ASCII Value|: |  48 | |Character|: | 0 | |ASCII Value|: |  49 | |Character|: | 1 | |ASCII Value|: |  50 | |Character|: | 2 | |ASCII Value|: |  51 | |Character|: | 3 |
|ASCII Value|: |  52 | |Character|: | 4 | |ASCII Value|: |  53 | |Character|: | 5 | |ASCII Value|: |  54 | |Character|: | 6 | |ASCII Value|: |  55 | |Character|: | 7 |
|ASCII Value|: |  56 | |Character|: | 8 | |ASCII Value|: |  57 | |Character|: | 9 | |ASCII Value|: |  58 | |Character|: | : | |ASCII Value|: |  59 | |Character|: | ; |
|ASCII Value|: |  60 | |Character|: | < | |ASCII Value|: |  61 | |Character|: | = | |ASCII Value|: |  62 | |Character|: | > | |ASCII Value|: |  63 | |Character|: | ? |
|ASCII Value|: |  64 | |Character|: | @ | |ASCII Value|: |  65 | |Character|: | A | |ASCII Value|: |  66 | |Character|: | B | |ASCII Value|: |  67 | |Character|: | C |
|ASCII Value|: |  68 | |Character|: | D | |ASCII Value|: |  69 | |Character|: | E | |ASCII Value|: |  70 | |Character|: | F | |ASCII Value|: |  71 | |Character|: | G |
|ASCII Value|: |  72 | |Character|: | H | |ASCII Value|: |  73 | |Character|: | I | |ASCII Value|: |  74 | |Character|: | J | |ASCII Value|: |  75 | |Character|: | K |
|ASCII Value|: |  76 | |Character|: | L | |ASCII Value|: |  77 | |Character|: | M | |ASCII Value|: |  78 | |Character|: | N | |ASCII Value|: |  79 | |Character|: | O |
|ASCII Value|: |  80 | |Character|: | P | |ASCII Value|: |  81 | |Character|: | Q | |ASCII Value|: |  82 | |Character|: | R | |ASCII Value|: |  83 | |Character|: | S |
|ASCII Value|: |  84 | |Character|: | T | |ASCII Value|: |  85 | |Character|: | U | |ASCII Value|: |  86 | |Character|: | V | |ASCII Value|: |  87 | |Character|: | W |
|ASCII Value|: |  88 | |Character|: | X | |ASCII Value|: |  89 | |Character|: | Y | |ASCII Value|: |  90 | |Character|: | Z | |ASCII Value|: |  91 | |Character|: | [ |
|ASCII Value|: |  92 | |Character|: | \ | |ASCII Value|: |  93 | |Character|: | ] | |ASCII Value|: |  94 | |Character|: | ^ | |ASCII Value|: |  95 | |Character|: | _ |
|ASCII Value|: |  96 | |Character|: | ` | |ASCII Value|: |  97 | |Character|: | a | |ASCII Value|: |  98 | |Character|: | b | |ASCII Value|: |  99 | |Character|: | c |
|ASCII Value|: | 100 | |Character|: | d | |ASCII Value|: | 101 | |Character|: | e | |ASCII Value|: | 102 | |Character|: | f | |ASCII Value|: | 103 | |Character|: | g |
|ASCII Value|: | 104 | |Character|: | h | |ASCII Value|: | 105 | |Character|: | i | |ASCII Value|: | 106 | |Character|: | j | |ASCII Value|: | 107 | |Character|: | k |
|ASCII Value|: | 108 | |Character|: | l | |ASCII Value|: | 109 | |Character|: | m | |ASCII Value|: | 110 | |Character|: | n | |ASCII Value|: | 111 | |Character|: | o |
|ASCII Value|: | 112 | |Character|: | p | |ASCII Value|: | 113 | |Character|: | q | |ASCII Value|: | 114 | |Character|: | r | |ASCII Value|: | 115 | |Character|: | s |
|ASCII Value|: | 116 | |Character|: | t | |ASCII Value|: | 117 | |Character|: | u | |ASCII Value|: | 118 | |Character|: | v | |ASCII Value|: | 119 | |Character|: | w |
|ASCII Value|: | 120 | |Character|: | x | |ASCII Value|: | 121 | |Character|: | y | |ASCII Value|: | 122 | |Character|: | z | |ASCII Value|: | 123 | |Character|: | { |
|ASCII Value|: | 124 | |Character|: | | | |ASCII Value|: | 125 | |Character|: | } | |ASCII Value|: | 126 | |Character|: | ~ |
```

If you don't want `|ASCII Value|: |  32 | |Character|: |   |` on it's own line, change the `if v % 4 == 0:` to `if v % 4 == 3:`

Comment: I looked up the string format stuff. I think that's pretty cool. Could you please explain to me why changing v modulo 4 ==0 to == to '3' puts the first element back with the others? I was initially confused at why it was separate..